# Installing (and using) numpy without access to a compiler or binaries

Tags: python, numpy

Assuming performance is not an issue, is there a way to deploy numpy in a environment where a compiler is unavailable, and no pre-built binaries can be installed?

Alternatively, is there a pure-python numpy implementation?

Comment: @blindJesse that looks interesting, but it's windows only, so I guess it will contain prebuilt binaries? I'm looking for a cross-platform technique to install numpy programatically. Though I guess it would be possible to detect each platform individually...

Comment: Yeah I wondered about the platform...it sounds like you're trying to use it in a program install? I'm sure it's been done, but don't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> a compiler is unavailable, and no pre-built binaries can be installed

This... makes numpy impossible.  If you cannot install numpy binaries, and you cannot compile numpy source code, then you are left with no options.